# Quotient Space and Quotient Topology Definitions

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show an equivalence between these two definitions:

(1) **The Quotient Space:** Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map from a topological space $X$ to a set $Y$ and define $\pi: X \to \frac{X}{\sim}$ as a surjective function.

We define the quotient topology, $\tau_{\frac{X}{\sim}} = \{ U \subset Y : f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_{X} \}$.

(2) **The Quotient Map:** Any function $\pi: (X, \tau_X) \to (Y, \tau_Y)$ is a quotient map if every $ U \subset Y$ is open iff $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is open.

---

**(1) $\to$ (2)**

Let (1) hold. Then if $U \subset Y$ and $U$ is open, $U \in \tau_Y = \tau_{\frac{X}{\sim}}$. But ***does*** $\tau_Y = \tau_{\frac{X}{\sim}}$? Then $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_X$. Conversely, let $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_X$. Then each $U^{\subset Y} \in \tau_{\frac{X}{\sim} = \tau_Y}$. (2) follows.

**(2) $\to$ (1)**

If every $U \subset Y$ is open iff every $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is open, we have that $U^{\subset Y} \in \tau_{Y}=\tau_{\frac{X}{\sim}}$ if $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_X$. This shows (1).

What do you think? Thx!